# Bootstrap columns stacking vertically on mobile device

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap grid layout. I do not want the columns to stack vertically even on small devices.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are stacking vertically because you're using **Bootstrap 4**, and the `-xs-` infix is no longer used. Just use `col-4`..

```
  <div class="container border-show center-div">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 border-show">1</div>
      <div class="col-4 border-show">2</div>
      <div class="col-4 border-show">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/sCct2CzZte

Answer (score -1):

I can't quite make out the question because the HTML you posted does exactly what you want it to do: It never stacks the columns vertically for that row.

Could you clarify what you're trying to ask? See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a reference of how to ask good questions.

Comment: It should never stack the columns vertically, but it is. That is what I can not understand. Here is a link: 
https://codepen.io/devanshchawla/pen/EmmNEw
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The example you posted does not stack the columns vertically. Do you have and addons in your browser that could influence the layout?

Comment: It is stacking the columns vertically when I access it using my mobile. I have tried  google chrome and firefox. I don't think I have any addons or plugins.

Comment: If you have it publicly accessible somewhere, please post the link. I tried to reproduce it with a screen of 100*100px where it still does not stack.

Please edit your question and post the full HTML and any additional CSS you included and/or edited.

Comment: @ZimSystem Did so, what exactly are you referring to?