# Grid system inside bootstrap form: inline select and input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm setting a form in bootstrap and I have this part:

```
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
             <select class="form-control" id="valueToFilter">
                  <option>Fecha</option>
             </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-">
            <select class="form-control" id="filterOperator">
                <option> > </option>
                <option> < </option>
                <option> = </option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <label for="filterValue" class="sr-only">Filter value</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterValue">
        </div>
    </div>
```

So it looks right in desktop:

[image: desktop]

But it looks 'not-inlined' in mobile

[image: mobile]

I think I have plenty of space because the select is just an operator (>, < or =) so, there is any way I can force the inline for those two members? why is col-xs-2 not working at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no longer a -xs infix in Bootstrap 4.**

```
   <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-2 col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" id="filterOperator">
                <option> &gt; </option>
                <option> &lt; </option>
                <option> = </option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <label for="filterValue" class="sr-only">Filter value</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterValue">
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/HqVYxsu8I7

---

[Read the Bootstrap grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content)
[Bootstrap columns stacking vertically on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706222/bootstrap-columns-stacking-vertically-on-mobile-device/43706938#43706938)

Comment: ...
Thanks man. 3 hours looking for documentation and stuff in stackoverflow and Occam's razor.