# Trying to make 16 squares with bootsrtap and it isnt working, i dont know why

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to make 16 squares on my website using bootstrap yet it isnt working and i dont know why. i used "col-xs-3" yet it isnt setting the width, please help.

PS(of course i can set the width in CSS but i shouldnt have to)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <title>Match Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="gameInstructions col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <h1>Match Game</h1>
        <h2>Rules</h2>
        <p>Click on a card to reveal the number on the other side. Click on a second card to try and find a match to the first. If you succeed, the pair will be removed from play. If not, try again!</p>
        <h2>How To Win</h2>
        <p>You win when all pairs have been found.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="game"class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 card"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/js/match-game.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/js/tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/*"Work Sans" Font*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Work Sans'), local('WorkSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/worksans/v5/QGYsz_wNahGAdqQ43Rh_fKDp.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Work Sans Bold'), local('WorkSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/worksans/v5/QGYpz_wNahGAdqQ43Rh3x4X8mNhN.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local('Work Sans Black'), local('WorkSans-Black'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/worksans/v5/QGYpz_wNahGAdqQ43Rh3_4f8mNhN.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/*Universal Styling*/
html{
  font-size: 14px;
}

body{
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(255,242,242);
  padding-top: 5.25rem;
}

p{
  color: rgb(74, 74, 74);
}

h1{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: rgb(32, 64, 86);
}

h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/*Specified Styling*/
.card{
  height: 12.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

the expected output would be 16 squares with 25% width and 12.5rem height each

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't write any text in your `column`. I just write some text in it and there will be columns displaying. See here i generated a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6exd8fr/) here.

Answer (score 0):

If your expexted output is 16 boxes then, provide some width to your **card** class.

```
.card{
    height: 12.5rem;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your sixteen box with same width within a row then provide width in calc:

```
.card{
  width: calc(100% / 16)
  height: 12.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The -xs- infix is no longer used in Bootstrap 4**

This is 16 card boxes on all device widths...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">.. </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="card">16 </div></div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/BtOgePpG7n

Related: [Bootstrap columns stacking vertically on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706222/bootstrap-columns-stacking-vertically-on-mobile-device/43706938#43706938)

Comment: Damn, ok i didnt know. Thanks. This one actually helped i dont think the others understood